# Intel AC 7260 Bluetooth Immediately Disconnects in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth, intel

I have been struggling with my Intel AC 7260 Dual Band for almost five months and really given up in periods. The wireless part of it usually works fine, but the Bluetooth adapter has nearly killed me. I finally got the Bluetooth driver to work in Windows 7 by downgrading to the Bluetooth driver version `3.1.1307.0366` for the card (luckily the vendor of my computer from had it around). Any other driver I have tried has failed. Now, In Ubuntu I have a long story with this card as well. To cut it short, here's my current state for the card in Ubuntu 13.10:

**Edit**
The downgrading of the Bluetooth driver in Windows 7 actually only worked until reboot, so that did not resolve the issue there.
**/Edit**

The Wifi generally works fine, but it disconnects every now and then in periods, sometimes once per hour. Mostly annoying, nothing too serious. The Bluetooth, however, is another story. Most often, the Bluetooth icon is loaded into the task bar, sometimes it is not (like now, after a suspend). At reboot it usually comes back. When the icon is there I can add devices and connect to them, but they are instantly disconnected. This is also true for `Bluetooth Manager` utility which I have also installed. Here I can also set devices to trusted. This seems to work fine, but I still cannot connect without disconnecting.

Note that I have tested my Bluetooth keyboard to my phone and my phone to my Bluetooth audio output. All of this works fine.

### Output from various system commands:

```
$ dmesg | grep Blue
[    3.279513] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    3.279526] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.279533] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.279535] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.279539] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.295312] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d2c
[    3.295314] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 2c
[    6.535819] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.535822] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.535828] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.539007] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.539016] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.539017] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  456.343021] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[  456.343030] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[ 2632.649682] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d00
[ 2632.649994] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[ 2632.765840] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
```

Not sure what happened at `2632` there, but it seems to have started using the firmware is located at

```
$ sudo find / -name ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
```

Kernel version:

```
$ uname -r
3.11.0-19-generic
```

My Wifi/Bluetooth card:

```
$ lspci | grep 7260
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 63)
```

Installed `bluez` stuff:

```
$ bluez <tab tab>
bluez-simple-agent    bluez-test-device     bluez-test-network
bluez-simple-service  bluez-test-discovery  bluez-test-serial
bluez-test-adapter    bluez-test-input      bluez-test-service
bluez-test-audio      bluez-test-manager    bluez-test-telephony
```

Contents of `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
[General]

# List of plugins that should not be loaded on bluetoothd startup
#DisablePlugins = network,input

# Default adaper name
# %h - substituted for hostname
# %d - substituted for adapter id
Name = %h-%d

# Default device class. Only the major and minor device class bits are
# considered.
Class = 0x000100

# How long to stay in discoverable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 180, i.e. 3 minutes.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay discoverable forever
DiscoverableTimeout = 180

# How long to stay in pairable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 0.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay pairable forever
PairableTimeout = 0

# Use some other page timeout than the controller default one
# which is 16384 (10 seconds).
PageTimeout = 8192

# Automatic connection for bonded devices driven by platform/user events.
# If a platform plugin uses this mechanism, automatic connections will be
# enabled during the interval defined below. Initially, this feature
# intends to be used to establish connections to ATT channels.
AutoConnectTimeout = 60

# What value should be assumed for the adapter Powered property when
# SetProperty(Powered, ...) hasn't been called yet. Defaults to true
InitiallyPowered = true

# Remember the previously stored Powered state when initializing adapters
RememberPowered = true

# Use vendor id source (assigner), vendor, product and version information for
# DID profile support. The values are separated by ":" and assigner, VID, PID
# and version.
# Possible vendor id source values: bluetooth, usb (defaults to usb)
#DeviceID = bluetooth:1234:5678:abcd

# Do reverse service discovery for previously unknown devices that connect to
# us. This option is really only needed for qualification since the BITE tester
# doesn't like us doing reverse SDP for some test cases (though there could in
# theory be other useful purposes for this too). Defaults to true.
ReverseServiceDiscovery = true

# Enable name resolving after inquiry. Set it to 'false' if you don't need
# remote devices name and want shorter discovery cycle. Defaults to 'true'.
NameResolving = true

# Enable runtime persistency of debug link keys. Default is false which
# makes debug link keys valid only for the duration of the connection
# that they were created for.
DebugKeys = false

# Enable the GATT functionality. Default is false
EnableGatt = false
```

`lsusb` shows

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:c531 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 147e:1002 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c06b Logitech, Inc. G700 Wireless Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 5986:0512 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am starting to freak out on this one. I could go for `Ubuntu 14.04` and see what happens, but I want to try other stuff first. Maybe re-installing something, maybe remove some firmware? Maybe some changes in the `main.conf` file? Any comments are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had almost forgotten this question, but for future references it seems that the problem was with the Wifi/Bluetooth AC 7260 Dual Band itself. It is not able to use Wifi *and* bluetooth properly at the same time. My solution was thus to buy a usb bluetooth dongle for using bluetooth while only using the Wifi with the AC 7260. Not a too good solution, but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on my Dell E7440 running Ubuntu 14.04 / Linux Mint 17.1 with kernel 3.19 and latest firmware blobs. After pairing a bluetooth device, wifi becomes unusable. But both bluetooth and wifi work without problems when the other one is disabled.

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi recommends to disable bluetooth coexistance. To do so, load the `iwlwifi` module with `bt_coex_active=0`.

To make this setting permanent at start, type the following into a terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/wifi.conf
```

The file should be empty. Then add the following line:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

Save the changes and reboot.

**Edit:**

Unfortunately, this does not work :-(

I don't know what I tested, but setting `bx_coex_active=0` disables bluetooth completely.

I also tested using a 502.11g connection instead of a faster 502.11n one. The module option to disable 502.11n is  `11n_disable=1`. It sounds a bit better, but in my testcase (listening internet radio via my Jambox) I cannot reliably tell if the wifi or the BT connection is bad.

**Edit 2:**

Reloading the `iwlwifi` kernel module after pairing with the Jambox also helped to get a better Wifi connection. In a console, type

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

I tried this originally because I wasn't able to connect the Wifi even with disabled BT. Also, the Bluetooth driver remains loaded regardless of options like `bx_coex_active=0`.

Lastly, changing the Wifi router from channel 6 to channel 13 also seems to help a little bit as well, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I use ac7260 but Ubuntu supports it natively only since kernel v4.1+
you need better upgrade to ubuntu 20+ .
even then the bluetooth will sometimes work with many cuts.
simplest reset solve it:

```
hciconfig hci0 down
rmmod btusb
modprobe btusb
hciconfig hci0 up
```

see  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602730/bluetooth-intermittently-disconnects/602739#602739